# My blog hosted on github and jekyll suddenly navigates to a different link

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I had created a blog using Jekyll and github a month ago but recently I have noticed something strange. If I navigate to my blog and after a few navigations my blog's url shows as https://jinudaniel-fa13183e7c.drafts.github.io/ instead of https://jinudaniel.github.io/.
I am not sure why this is happening. Please help me.

Comment: Seems like a Github pages hiccup.

Comment: Can you try to narrow the problem down a bit? Is there an exact link that's misbehaving?